# Memory usage not decreasing when dismissing viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a `UINavigationController` and 2 `UIViewControllers` linked to it which one has lots of different `UIViews` in it. No code behind them, they are 100% original from the framework.

[image]

Now, whats happening to the memory usage is it starts at `4MB` and once I press `Button` to go to the second `ViewController` the memory goes up to `5MB`, whne going back it stays at `5MB` and moving back and forth increases memory usage just a liiitle bit each time.

Im running on device and watching the usage in XCode's `Debug Navigator`.

Ive always wondered why this is happening and not really understood why.

Comment: how are you going back to your rootviewcontroller?

Comment: @GamalielTellezOrtiz Its a segue and I have no code to shoe because everything is default, its a default back button in the navigationbar

Comment: if you are only using segues to go back and forth between view controllers using segues only that is why you memory keeps increasing. Segues just push/present a new instance of the viewcontroller, hence your stack of view controllers only increases. You need to dismiss/pop your view controller when you are going back

Comment: As tou can see in my image I only have one segue, Of course I know that. popViewController is used

Comment: I dont have a new segue going back to the old one, as I said, the default back button is used in navigationbar